# Server return error 503 after load NodeJS files

Tags: node.js

First time I´m setting a server to host a PWA. After load basic NodeJS file I am facing problem to see the picture under the images/user folder.

Error -> Cannot GET /images/user/default_user_pic.png

Folder structure

```
 Public
  |-index.html
  |-node_modules
  |-images
     |-user
     |  |-default_user_pic.png
     |-channel
```

NodeJs

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const path = require('path')

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Umbler - Express server started on port %s', port);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "temporarysite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Nodejs temporary site",
  "author": "test",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.x.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: The error says "path is not defined", you need to require it.

Comment: @Phix thanks.. I put const path = require('path') and site is openning. Facing the problem to load the picture.. updated the question.